# Python - coin problem using loops isn't working

Tags: python, list, debugging

I have some Python code I've been working on for a few days and I think I am close to figuring it out, but some test values being passed through don't give the right answer. The objective is to give a list of 0s and 1s representing coins. The program will determine the max number of adjacent coins that can be achieved after flipping only one coin.

For example, given array A consisting of six numbers:

```
A = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0]
```

the function returns 4. The code I have below works with this example but if I input a list such as

```
A = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

I get 9 instead of what should be 7. I'm not sure what exactly is wrong but any help is appreciated.

```
def solution(A):
    n = len(A)
    result = 0
    for i in range(n - 1):
        if (A[i + 1] == A[i]):
            result = result + 1
    r = -1
    for i in range(n):
        count = 0
        if (i > 0):
            if (A[i - 1] != A[i]):
                count = count + 1
            else:
                count = count - 1
        if (i < n - 1):
            if (A[i + 1] != A[i]):
                count = count + 1
            else:
                count = count - 1
        r = max(r, count)
    return result + r
```

Comment: `result` counts number of adjacent pairs with same value. What does `r` count?

Comment: This sounds like a G/foobar question. Yes?

Comment: r is set to 0 so that when getting the value of count it doesn't go below 0

Comment: Just had to look up what G/foobar is and no that's not what this is for.

Comment: What is the point of the first loop? Even better: care to explain how your algorithm works?

Comment: Please do *not* delete your question when it has received a useful answer.

Comment: The standard approach with recursion would be to compute `max(length-of-string-of-ones-containing-1-zero, length-of-string-of-zeros-containing-1-one)`. But currently your code `result` counts all adjacent pairs in the entire list A; this is not what you want, it will be overcount. Look closely at why s(A) should be 7, not 9. Show us where that subsequence of length-7 should start and finish in A. Throw away your approach with `result, r` and rewrite it.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you don't look like you are in the right direction (unless I am missing something). You can solve this problem in two ways. First way is easier, second way is more elegant.

1. Just flip each item, and count the maximum number of adjacent `0`s and `1`s. This will be an `O(N^2)` solution.
2. Count number of "islands" of `0`s and `1`s. Then iterate over those numbers. This way, you can find your answer in a linear time. For instance say you have

```
A = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

this will give you

```
islands = [2,3,1,1,5,1]
```

which means you have: 2 `0`s, 3 `1`s, 1 `1`, 1 `0`, 5 `0`s, 1 `1`.
Then iterate over `islands` and check how much you can expand each island. I.e.

1. First island: 2 `0`s. Can be made 3 `0`s by flipping `A[2]`
2. Second island: 3 `1`s. Can be made 5 `1`s by flipping `A[5]`
3. Third island: 1 `0`....
4. Forth island: 1 `1`....
5. Fifth island: 5 `0`s. Can be made 7 `1`s by flipping `A[6]`
6. ...

I can give you more hint/code if you want.

Comment: This is more efficient but likely to confuse the OP more than the standard O(N^2) approach with recursion, computing the `max(length-of-string-of-ones-containing-1-zero, length-of-string-of-zeros-containing-1-one)`